# Update tab in Loop Not Working in Chrome Extension Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension that will loop through some specific URLs in one tab. I am using chrome local storage to store the URLs. Here is the `background.js` part where I'm trying to do the tab update,

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.message === 'sending_links_of_posts') {
    changeUrl(request);
  }
});

function changeUrl(request) {
  const urlArr = request.url;
  console.log(urlArr);
  chrome.storage.local.set({ urls: urlArr }, function () {
    console.log('Urls stored. \n' + urlArr);
  });
  chrome.storage.local.get(['urls'], function (result) {
    for (let i = 1; i < result.urls.length; i++) {
      console.log('Value currently is ' + result.urls[i]);
      chrome.tabs.update(undefined, {
        url: 'https://m.facebook.com' + urlArr[i],
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Chrome only opens the first link tab it gets. I've `tabs` and `storage` permission in my `manifest.json`. I've tried `chrome.tabs.create`, and that creates new tabs for all the URLs. But I need to update the current tab only. I am using the `manifest_version: 2`.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from a discord channel helped me find the answer. The function I want to implement can be achieved using this code.

```js
let i;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.message === 'sending_links_of_posts') {
    // initialize index
    i = 0;
    // add urls to local storage
    const urlArr = request.url;
    console.log(urlArr);
    chrome.storage.local.set({ urls: urlArr }, function () {
      console.log('Urls stored. \n' + urlArr);
    });
    // start changing the url
    changeUrl(i);
  }
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  // only update after the page has loaded
  if(changeInfo.status === "complete") {
    i++;
    changeUrl(i);
  }
});

function changeUrl(i) {
  chrome.storage.local.get(['urls'], function (result) {
      if (i >= result.urls.length) {
        return;
      }
      console.log('Value currently is ' + result.urls[i]);
      chrome.tabs.update(undefined, {
        url: 'https://m.facebook.com/' + result.urls[i],
      });

  });
}
```

Wrapping the `changeUrl` function into a `setTimeout` or implementing a `sleep` function can help to slow the URL changing process.